# Python Jupyter Notebook: How to print unicode characters from wikipedia hex value (like U+1F0A1)?

Tags: python, unicode

I would like to use the playing card characters in unicode within a jupyter notebook.

Unicode codes are here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode

Printing the suits works

```
print('\u2660')
```

returns

♠

As an example, the Ace of Spades  unicode is U+1F0A1.

I can paste that character and print it.

```
print('')
```

And I can encode this

```
''.encode('utf-8')
```

b'\xf0\x9f\x82\xa1'

But how do I print this by the code "U+1F0A1" from wikipedia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is another type of escape code (capital U) that requires eight digits:

```
>>> print('\U0001F0A1')
```

You can also print by converting a number:

```
>>> chr(0x1f0a1)
''
>>> print(chr(0x1f0a1))
```

So you can programmatically generate a 52-card desk as:

```
>>> suit = 0x1f0a0,0x1f0b0,0x1f0c0,0x1f0d0
>>> rank = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14
>>> for s in suit:
...     for r in rank:
...         print(chr(s+r),end='')
...     print()
...
```